# Chicago-style "additional resources" at end of chapter

Tags: formatting, chicago-manual-of-style

I'm writing a physics Ph.D. thesis in Chicago style and I'd like to include an "additional resources" section at the end of each chapter. This section would include articles, websites, etc. which I may not necessarily have directly used in a section (and therefore don't need to cite), but which I think an interested reader may find enlightening. An example would be a journal article which includes a long derivation of an equation which I reference, but which is really out of the scope of my thesis itself.

At the moment, I make a "mini bibliography" (called "Additional Resources") --- formatted exactly like a normal Chicago Bibliography --- at the end of each chapter, and have the "Bibliography" at the end of the whole thesis. Does having this "additional resources" section agree with Chicago style? Are there any clear guidelines on formatting Ph.D. theses in the Chicago handbook? I've tried searching online but all I can find are guidelines on how to *cite* Ph.D. theses, not how to actually format them as they're being written.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would format your 'additional resources' page as if it were Appendix A directly following your regular bibliography. If you already have appendices, you can simply order them however you wish. I envision the general advantage of doing this is to free yourself of styling restrictions otherwise present in the rest of your dissertation. For instance, in my mind it would be fine to list several websites informally in an appendix rather than forcing yourself to use their actual Chicago-style citations. You can find examples of this approach in more popular books.

Alternatively, I thought it acceptable to include uncited works in your Bibliography if they were formative for you on the subject matter. In this way, the bibliography can fulfill a secondary function as a 'further reading' list.

If you can go to your institution's library and look at the actual Chicago Manual of Style, it would answer Chicago-related formatting question definitely. You may also have institution access to the full [Chicago Manual of Style online](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html). You will need to sign in either here or through your institution's online library.

Alternatively a good book I've read that seems targeted specifically for you is:

[A Manual for Writers of Research Papers, Theses, and Dissertations, Eighth Edition: Chicago Style for Students and Researchers (Chicago Guides to Writing, Editing, and Publishing) 8th Edition by Kate L. Turabian](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226816389)

It's less than 20 dollars and acts a succinct summary of the actual CMoS without having to buy or lug around that massive, expensive book.